# What is the default wowza live stream name?

Tags: live-streaming, wowza

I have spent hours trying to run the live stream from our Wowza server, but I can't seem to make it running. The quick guide says, that the default stream name is "myStream" but this doesn't work. The VOD example works just fine but the live one gives me a headache.

Where can I change the stream name? Or where can I find what the stream name is?
I have also tried to user the Transcoder, where you can change the stream name to whichever stream name you desire to have in the `transcoder.xml` like `<StreamName>mp4:live_sample</StreamName>` but it was for nothing.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the live stream comes from the encoded stream that you are feeding into Wowza.

I would ping the Wowza support team if you can't figure it out.  The support is free.